# How to get location with dbid in 2D

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How can I get location (x and y) of object with dbid in 2D viewer? What about properties of object with dbid? The format of the 2D file is dwg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What about properties of object with dbid?

You can use getSelection() method followed by `getProperties(dbid, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback)` which
Gets the properties for an ID. Once the properties are returned, the method raises a onPropertiesReady event.

You can check the Documentation here. https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/