# How to find location (x,y,z)-coordinate of an object based on the DBID in a 2D Map?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

My project requires me to be able to find the object's geometry based on the DBID in a 2D map. My team has tried using the bounding box approach to estimate an object's coordinates based on the DBID, but this approach only works well in a 3D map, and it is very inaccurate in a 2D setting.

I have also discovered a technique other users have used before to approach this problem: [How to get location with dbid in 2D view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47978314/how-to-get-location-with-dbid-in-2d-view). However, this technique is not currently applicable because it involves using namespaces/functions that are not accessible. In addition, I have tried some other approaches like finding the coordinates through the object's properties. But it turns out that the coordinate is not stored inside the object's properties.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this thread instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48326349/7745569

The `avp` means `Autodesk.Viewing.Private` namespace.